# Teleport Player From Void To Spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a Sky PvP server using only command blocks! If a player dies to another player I want them to drop their items on death, but when they fall down from island, I want to keep their inventory. How can i do this using command blocks?

Comment: What have you tried to make this happen on your own.  Arqade doesn't mind helping, but we do expect you to make an attempt on your own before asking here.  That way, when someone provides an answer, it's specific to the issue you're having, where you're stuck, that sort of thing.  And we get a better question, so everybody wins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a clock, run these commands in this order:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /effect @p[y=-100,dy=99] resistance 1 5
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /tp @p[y=-100,dy=99] X Y Z
```

Replace X Y Z with where you want them to be teleported back up to. The first command just gives a short resistance effect to stop the player from dying of fall damage.